# Branch multipicity of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Say $C_1$ and $C_2$ are curve classes on a smooth projective complex surface $X$.  (In my case, $X$ is toric.)  Let $P$ be a point on $X$.

Let $D_i$ be a divisor in the class $C_i$, and let $m_i$ be the maximum multiplicity of a branch of $D_i$ at $P$.  Let $M_i$ be the maximum of all $m_i$ taken over all divisors $D_i$.

Let $M$ be the maximum multiplicity of a branch of a divisor in the class $C_1+C_2$ at $P$.  So that's a maximum taken over all divisors in the class $C_1+C_2$, and over all branches of such curves.

Is it true that $M\leq M_1+M_2$?  If so, why?  If not, why not?  Any advice would be gratefully received -- thanks!

Comment: Hi David.  Let $\omega$, be a primitive $3$rd root of unity.  Let $X$ be the blowing up of $\mathbb{P}^2 = \text{Proj}\ k[u,v,w]$ at the $4$ points $q_1=[1,\omega,1]$, $r_1=[1,\omega^2,1]$, $q_2=[i,1,1]$ and $r_2=[-i,1,1]$.  Let $P$ be the point mapping to $[0,0,1]$.   For $i=1,2,$ let $C_i$ equal the class of the strict transform a plane conic containing $q_i$ and $r_i$. Then $M_1$ and $M_2$ both equal $1$: the only divisor $D_i$ that is singular at $P$ has two smooth branches.  However, the strict transform of $\text{Zero}(y^3z-x^4)$ has multiplicity $M=3$.

Comment: That's beautiful!  Thanks for that example … but it means another nice theory has run aground on the rocks of reality.  Oh well.